# Conditional formatting help on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Basically I'm trying to apply this really simple formula to each row in this table. The formula at the top is what I'm using. As you can see by the random cell my cursor is on, the formula is currently equal to false. But for some reason, the third cell is highlighted in row 2. Firstly, the formatting is supposed to apply to the entire row, so I don't know why it is only applied to C2. Secondly, why is it highlighting at all, when the equation is clearly false?

Side note: Yes, I know I'm using the third row to highlight the second row, but I'm just trying to get the formula to work right now.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So what exactly (in words) are you trying to do? "I want this red when that is... and the other is ...".

Comment: Please as @marikamitsos has suggested let your question be clear. What exactly are you expecting to happen. Also maybe you could give [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a read, to get helpful insight on how to improve your questions.

Answer (score 1):

use this formula instead:

```
=($A2*$B2)+($A2*$C2)+($B2*$C2)
```

on range **A2:C**

[image: 0]

---

the oposite would be:

```
=NOT(($A2*$B2)+($A2*$C2)+($B2*$C2))*(A2<>"")
```